# How to set ip addresses given up by my ISP

Tags: ip, isp

My ISP gave me 6 host IP ex 124.16.59.240/29 this belongs to the same subnet.

And they gave me another set of IP addresses that belong to different subnet ex-124.16.63.145/30 it has 2 host IP of which 124.16.63.146 is gateway.

what I am trying to do is, insert the raw bandwidth provided by my ISP to a Switch and take output through two ports using ethernet cable,one cable goes to my server with ip address 124.16.63.145 which is working another cable goes to my router with the IP address 124.16.59.241.

my server is working and i I can ping to its gateway but i cannot ping my routers gateway.Please help

Comment: Are you saying the router can't ping its own gateway? What is the router's IP address? What is its gateway? (You gave us lots of information about the device that's working but told us nothing about the device that's not working.)

Answer (score 2):

Generally when an ISP gives you both a /30 and a larger block of IP address, the /30 is for the connection between your router and them. Your router is expected to route the larger block.

This is almost certainly your setup if they didn't provide a gateway address for the /29. That gateway would be your router, and you can assign its LAN interface any IP address inside the /29 that you want.

So your router should have two Ethernet interfaces, one for your ISP and one for your LAN. The ISP interface should be numbered 124.16.64.145 and your router should have a default route to 124.16.64.146.

You can number the router interface in your LAN anything inside that /29 that you want. Other devices on the /29 should be switched to the router's LAN interface. Their default gateway should be the router's interface IP on the LAN side.

So:

1. For the /30: [ISP] <-> [Router/WAN]
2. For the /29: [Router/LAN] <-> [Switch] <-> [Other Devices]

Your ISP should have given you sufficient configuration information to make this clear. If you're still unclear about what they expect, you should ask them.

If your switch has VLAN capabilities, you can use a router with a single Ethernet port if it also supports VLANs. You can even bridge both the LAN and WAN sides if you must and assign a single router interface two IP addresses, but the IP setup is still the same.